# Which is greater, PHP?

Tags: php, comparison

Im writing a very simple program in PHP, but it keeps saying that 10<5.

Here is the code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<$m; $i++){
    $lastIndex = $length - 1;
    $v = $alice[$i];
    echo "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
    echo "Start, i = $i and alice[i] = $alice[$i] \r\n";
    for ($j=$lastIndex; $j>=0; $j--){
        echo "j = $j and newAr[j] = $ar[$j] \r\n \r\n";     
        echo "Before if, now check if ar[j] = $ar[$j] > $v = alice[i] \r\n 
        \r\n";
        if ($ar[$j] > $v){
            $rank = $j + 2;  
            $lastIndex = $j;
            echo "Inside if: ar[j] = $ar[$j] > $v = alice[i], now rank = $rank = 
            $j + 2 = j + 2 \r\n \r\n ";
            break;
        }
        else{
            echo "went into else: ar[j] = $ar[$j] < $v = alice[i] \r\n \r\n";
        }
        if ($ar[$j] == $v){
            $rank = $j + 1;
            $lastIndex = $j;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($j < 0){
        $rank = 1;
    }
    echo "Alices point is $alice[$i] which gives rank $rank \r\n ";
    //echo $rank;
}
```

And im getting this output:

Start, i = 0 and alice[i] = 5 
j = 4 and newAr[j] = 10

Before if, now check if ar[j] = 10

> 5 = alice[i]

went into else: ar[j] = 10
 < 5 = alice[i]

j = 3 and newAr[j] = 20

Before if, now check if ar[j] = 20 > 5 = alice[i]

Inside if: ar[j] = 20 > 5 = alice[i], now rank = 5 = 3 + 2 = j + 2

Alices point is 5 which gives rank 5

I still believe that it is a tiny error which gives the confusion,
but I have overlooked it for too many hours now, if someone can help.

As you can see, the for loop runs the code more times, 
and this is the only time it doesn't work.

Before the given code, I handle the array that I use. But that shouldn't
do anything.

Comment: Just a little note about the text you print out from the `else`: The opposite of `>` is not `<`, but `<=`.

Comment: What's the contents of `$alice` and `$ar`?

Comment: As for your problem, are the "numbers" actually *numbers* and not strings? Because `"10"` *is* (lexiographically) smaller than `"5"` (in most encodings, definitely in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Comment: I can't reproduce this with some arbitrary inputs. Here's the [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d92f6548e8b8773802a8f50f4204140b975f2700). Do give us an update with a version of this sandbox that reproduces the issue.

Comment: The first array input I get is this: 100 100 50 40 40 20 10. Then i use array_unique to get this:  printing first array 
 Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [2] => 50
    [3] => 40
    [5] => 20
    [6] => 10

) Then I wrote my own alg which gives this: Here we print ar: 
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 40
    [3] => 20
    [4] => 10

) $alice contains this: 5 25 50 120

Comment: Well it works in the sandbox. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bb6a6c077db361e92af57677f07d0c76e3b85e2